# Is arithmetic overflow/underflow generally checked in .Net framework methods?

Tags: c#

For example, let's use the Add method of the ArrayList class.  If I am using the default compiler settings in Visual Studio C# project in which arithmetic overflow is not checked, would ArrayList.Add() throw an OverflowException if I added too many items?  Would surrounding the method call with `checked` or `unchecked` make any difference?

BTW, I would write a test program to determine the answer to this question if I had Visual Studio available to me right now.

Comment: How are you going to overflow ArrayList.Add()? by Adding more elements than Array.LongLength?

Comment: @Matt Greer. Yes, or something like that I think.

Comment: That's  9,223,372,036,854,775,807 elements :) I'm not sure I'd worry about it. At least, not in this context, overflow may affect you in other areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general no the BCL does not run with overflow checking enabled.  Enabling it in your application will have no affect on already compiled binaries only on your code.

Imagine all of the problems that would arise if you could control how the BCL code executed.  Every time you authored an arithmetic expression you would have to consider how it would function in both scenarios in order to have 100% reliable code.  Because anyone could change the semantics by using a `checked` / `unchecked` block to call you.

Think of all of the fun you could have with security sensitive API's if you could turn off overflow checking in places they expect it to function.

Comment: That makes sense. So do you know what would happen if you tried to add more than Int32.MaxValue items to an array list?  I am assuming that is the max since the Add method returns an Int32 that is the index of the added item. The MSDN documentation does not say.

Answer (score 0):

its a build option, you can change it in the solution settings (clickibng on the corresponding checkbox)